# Indexing in mongoose documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I a working on a search feature in which I have to search over multiple fields in a documents.

I have following cases:

1) Get all documents where field1,field2,field3,field4 matches the string (nayyar)

2) Get all documents where field1,field2,field3,field4 matches the string (nayyar) AND gender should be (input value) or 'N/A'.

3) Get all documents where field1,field2,field3,field4 matches the string (nayyar) AND age should be between ageHigh and ageLow AND gender should be (input value) or 'N/A'.

4) Get all documents where field1,field2,field3,field4 matches the string (nayyar) AND age should be between ageHigh and ageLow AND gender should be (input value) or 'N/A' AND ArrayField in 'atoz'.

```
var Schema = new Schema({
lowAge          :   {
                        type: Number, 
                        default: 0 
                    },
highAge         :   {
                        type: Number, 
                        default: 0
                    },
gender          :   {
                        type: String,
                        default: 'N/A'
                    },
field1          :   {
                        type: String
                    },
field2          :   {
                        type: String
                    },
field3          :   {
                        type: String
                    },
field4          :   {
                        type: String
                    },
arrayField      :   {
                        type: [String]
                    }
});


Schema.index({field1:1, field2:1, field3:1, field4:1});
Schema.index({field1:1, field2:1, field3:1, field4:1, arrayField:1,lowAge:1, highAge:1, gender:1,});
```

Is it the correct way to index ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the idea of creating the index on the fields seem alright. However, creating index on all possible fields used in the query doesn't look correct.

All the queries listed in the post contain the four fields. If you create a compound index on all these 4 fields, I think it should be sufficient.

Also, you are defining the index at the schema level. When the application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. This could cause some performance impact.

You need to consider the following:-

1) Single field index i.e. creating four indexes one on each field.

Example:

```
db.collection.createIndex({field1 : 1});
```

Go for this option if you would need to find documents by either field1, field2, field3 or field4 or combination of one or more fields.

In this options, the indexes are independent. MongoDB will always end up using an index (i.e. one of the indexes).

2) Compound index i.e. creating one index with four fields

Example:

```
db.collection.createIndex({field1 : 1, field2 : 1, field3 : 1, field4 :1});
```

Go for this option if you would have field1 always.

If you don't have field1 in any scenario, the MongoDB wouldn't use index.

Comment: I am going to make collection at once by running a script. So performance during inserting data is not an issue. Yes, I will have four fields in all the cases and the other fields comes in different cases. Does it have any effect on the performance If I don't add index over the age and gender field ? and I will have 250,0000 documents on which I have to query.

Comment: After filtering the data by four fields, I presume you wouldn't have 250,0000 documents. You would have small subset of total, normally MongoDB should be ok to handle that without index. I have never seen all the fields in the document added in the index. Definitely, this is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your time and really this is very helpful for me.

Comment: Glad to help! May I request to accept the answer if it was useful?

Comment: I would like to share my code and the actual query with you for review. Is there any way to do this ?